# When do javascript broken promises or objects get garbage collected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, garbage-collection, closures

I was testing `promises` and `garbage collection` and according this [article](https://dankuck.github.io/2017/02/24/broken-js-promises.html), a `promise` like the one displayed in the code below, should get `garbage collected`. I used a `WeakMap` for checking as it should not interfere with the GC.

```js
var map = new WeakMap();
map.set(new Promise(function() {}), "test");

function doCheck() {
  console.log(map);
}
```

I tested the code above in chrome and the map still had a reference to the promise. Is my understanding of the `WeakMap` class wrong? If not, why is the promise not GC'ed?

Comment: Nothing will refer to the promise object, so it *could* be collected immediately. But that doesn't mean that the garbage collector will run immediately and actually collect it. Maybe you can start your JS environment with flags so that it exposes an interface to force GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Javascript engines uses Mark-and-sweep algorithm to check whether an object needs to be garbage collected or not.

> This algorithm assumes the knowledge of a set of objects called roots
>   (In JavaScript, the root is the global object). Periodically, the
>   garbage-collector will start from these roots, find all objects that
>   are referenced from these roots, then all objects referenced from
>   these, etc. Starting from the roots, the garbage collector will thus
>   find all reachable objects and collect all non-reachable objects.

Also, the map object is holding the references to the objects weakly. And there are no other references promise object, JS engine should clear the promise object in the next garbage collection cycle.

When I invoked first time doCheck(), map has the reference to the promise. But when I invoked second time, it was empty.

[image]

Comment: your answer is what i was expecting to happen when i ran the code, but the promise reference never got GC'ed.

Comment: When I invoked first time doCheck(), map has the reference to the promise. But when I invoked second time, it was empty.

Comment: @ I did the same from an `about:blank` chrome window console. it never got deleted.

Comment: Attached the screenshot of the working scenario. For me too sometimes, it didn't clear the reference. I think it depends on the garbage collection cycle.